# What is a better solution to divide numbers into even and odd?

Tags: python

```
Sequenz = []
Sequenz2 = []

for num in range (5,10000):
    while num % 2 == 0:
        Sequenz.append(num)
    else:
        while num % 2 == 1:
            Sequenz2.append(num)
    if num == 1:
        break
```

The intention of this code is to have a loop that checks if the number of the range is even or odd. It then puts it in the right Sequenz box.

Comment: Before we propose a better solution, what do you think of your current code?

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation? Some lines are indented differently than others.

Comment: What is your end goal with this code? To get a list of even and odd numbers?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], for tips like writing a good title and providing a [mre] including desired output and undesired output. As it stands, this *isn't* a solution, because it never finishes.

Comment: Hello david, 

you can also have something like that

```arr = range (5,10000)
    evens = sorted([element for element in arr if element % 2 ==0])
    odds = sorted([element for element in arr if element % 2 !=0])
```

Comment: @jakub is it possible to contact you privatly somewhere? Is there a chat function on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 3):

You can omit the `while` loops and check the parity of the number, then use `append()` directly to build up both lists:

```
Sequenz = []
Sequenz2 = []

for num in range (5, 10000):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        Sequenz2.append(num)
    else:
        Sequenz.append(num)

print(Sequenz, Sequenz2)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
even = []
odd = []

for num in range (100):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        even.append(num)
    else:
        odd.append(num)
```